# Select data when table is inserted with sqltransaction

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to select data from a table.
My problem is : I insert a row into a table using sqltransactions. This locks the table once insert is executed. I need to then select data from this table for some further execution by am not able to do it. I tried using nolock too but of no help.

my code is like this

```
Database.myConnection = new SqlConnection(Database.SQLConnectionString);
Database.myConnection.Open();

Database.myTrans =  Database.myConnection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, "SampleTransaction");
// Must assign both transaction object and connection
// to Command object for a pending local transaction
Database.myCommand = Database.myConnection.CreateCommand();
Database.myCommand.Connection = Database.myConnection;
Database.myCommand.Transaction = Database.myTrans;
Database.ExecuteSqlNonQuery("INSERT INTO customer(CustomerNo,CustomerName)VALUES('121','asd')");
```

Now i try to select from customer table but it gets deadlocked..I tried selecting with nolock too but no results..

Comment: I think you need to tell us what your using to connect to the database is this a c# question eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx

Comment: Also provide examples of what your code looks like

Comment: Am connecting to 2005 sql database through c#..

Comment: And what does your SELECT look like ie the c# bit?

Comment: Have you committed your transactions?

Comment: its just a simple "select * from customers where customerno = some other number..."

Comment: No i havent commited my transactions... I need to perform some more operations before the commit.

Comment: Ok the point I want to get to was to see if you were reusing the transaction object for your SELECT code - reusing it or at least the connection from the transaction object may solve your problem.

Comment: yes that works !!!!!!!!!!! What i had done is for inserts and updates created a global connection while for selectes a new connection was made....now comes another question i got datareaders inbetween my code before the commit, should i use the global connection here too.. will there be a problem if i close the reader connection?

Comment: Why is it that your performing an update then a read then an update? Why are you not reading everything upfront? OR perhaps you should look to use a store procedure...

Comment: actually my code is like this...

transaction start
Method1(Perform some Inserts Updates Selects)
Method2(Perform some Inserts Updates Selects)
Method3(Perform some Inserts Updates Selects)
transaction.commit

Answer (score 0):

Reuse your connection object for both the UPDATE and SELECT.

When performing multiple updates just pass the connection between the methods. Make sure to wrap with a USING statement

```
using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    Method1(conn);
    Method2(conn);
}
```